# What are the differences between Vampire and Lycan hybrids and purebred Vampires/Lycans?

Tags: underworld

Apart from V-L hybrids being able to be out in daylight compared to vampires having to remain in the shadows during daylight, what differences or benefits do hybrids have over purebred Vampires and Lycans?

Comment: Throughout the movies, they make a big deal that hybrids are more powerful than purebred Lycan/vampire. Wondering what are the differences that makes that statement true (apart from the obvious in my original question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abilities as follows:

> - Superhuman Strength: Even newly sired Hybrids possess strength equal    to or slightly above that of a Vampire Elder. Michael was
>     able to    fight Viktor immediately after becoming a Hybrid, and
>     before his    first feeding. He can also bend steel with his grip, and
>     kills the    oldest of all Werewolves by tearing the top-half of his
>     head off    shortly after reviving from death. Eve tosses a cabinet
>     high into the    air, shattering it; rips apart a Lycan and fights
>     Jacob Lane, another    Hybrid, on equal terms, and kills him by
>     ripping out his throat mere    minutes after coming off a powerful
>     anesthetic. Marcus, a    Vampire-Lycan Hybrid, is able to raise the
>     entrance to his brother's    tomb (an enormous stone door) without
>     using the key, pull on a rope    hard enough to bring a helicopter
>     crashing down from the air, and    fight hand-to-hand with Selene, a
>     Vampire-Corvinus Strain Hybrid    whose strength surpasses that of a
>     Vampire Elder.
> - Superhuman Speed:    Even having just turned, a Hybrid's speed surpasses that of both a    Vampire and a Lycan, with their movements
>     being almost unfollowable.
> - Superhuman Endurance: Hybrids can sustain many punches, blows and    other wounds by other superhumanly strong beings, while still being
>     able to fight back.
> - Superhuman Agility: Hybrids have a higher level    of agility than both Lycan and Vampires alike.
> - Superhuman Healing:    Their regenerative abilities are much more powerful than normal    Vampires and Lycans, allowing them to quickly
>     heal from wounds and    giving them total invulnerability to common
>     allergies of silver and    ultraviolet light. As displayed by Michael,
>     Hybrids even have the    capacity to heal from death, given their
>     bodies are still intact.    However, this advanced healing factor is
>     useless in cases of    dismemberment.

http://underworld.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Species

http://underworld.wikia.com/wiki/Hybrid